# Saving C# Expression Tree to a File

Tags: c#, debugging, expression, debug-symbols

I want to debug an expression and save the expression tree to a file:

```
var generator = DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator();
var document = Expression.SymbolDocument(fileName: "MyDebug.txt");
var debugInfo = Expression.DebugInfo(document, 6, 9, 6, 22);
var expressionBlock = Expression.Block(debugInfo, fooExpression);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expressionBlock, parameters);
lambda.CompileToMethod(method, generator);
var bakedType = type.CreateType();
return (type)bakedType.GetMethod(method.Name).Invoke(null, parameters);
```

How can I find or save "MyDebug.txt"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't comprehend what `SymbolDocument()` is...

```
var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("foo"), System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mod = asm.DefineDynamicModule("mymod", true);
var type = mod.DefineType("baz", TypeAttributes.Public);
var method = type.DefineMethod("go", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

Expression fooExpression = Expression.Divide(Expression.Constant(0), Expression.Constant(0));
var parameters = new ParameterExpression[0];
var generator = DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator();
var document = Expression.SymbolDocument(fileName: "MyDebug.txt");
var debugInfo = Expression.DebugInfo(document, 6, 9, 6, 22);
var expressionBlock = Expression.Block(debugInfo, fooExpression);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expressionBlock, parameters);

lambda.CompileToMethod(method, generator);
var bakedType = type.CreateType();
Func<int> method2 = (Func<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), bakedType.GetMethod(method.Name));

try
{
    int res = method2();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

The `Expression` I generated is something like `return 0/0;`. I execute it and trap the exception (note that I don't use the `Invoke` method, because the `Invoke` method would put the `DivisionByZeroException` as the `InnerException`).

The stack trace I output is something like:

in baz.go() in MyDebug.txt:row 6
in ConsoleApplication85.Program.Test()

You see the `MyDebug.txt:row` 6? They are your `SymbolDocument` and your `DebugInfo`.

A more complete example, taken from [Debugging Dynamically Generated Code (Reflection.Emit)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/debugging-dynamically-generated-code-reflection-emit).

```
static void Test()
{
    // create a dynamic assembly and module 
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("HelloWorld");
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

    // Mark generated code as debuggable. 
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rmbyers/debuggableattribute-and-dynamic-assemblies for explanation.        
    Type daType = typeof(DebuggableAttribute);
    ConstructorInfo daCtor = daType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes) });
    CustomAttributeBuilder daBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(daCtor, new object[] { 
    DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | 
    DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default });
    assemblyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(daBuilder);

    ModuleBuilder module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("HelloWorld.exe", true); // <-- pass 'true' to track debug info.

    var doc = Expression.SymbolDocument(@"Source.txt");

    // create a new type to hold our Main method 
    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = module.DefineType("HelloWorldType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

    // create the Main(string[] args) method 
    MethodBuilder methodbuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });

    // Create a local variable of type 'string', and call it 'xyz'
    var localXYZ = Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "xyz"); // Provide name for the debugger. 

    var generator = DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator();
    var debugInfo1 = Expression.DebugInfo(doc, 2, 1, 2, 100);

    // Emit sequence point before the IL instructions. This is start line, start col, end line, end column, 

    // Line 2: xyz = "hello"; 
    var assign = Expression.Assign(localXYZ, Expression.Constant("Hello world!"));

    // Line 3: Write(xyz); 
    MethodInfo infoWriteLine = typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    var debugInfo2 = Expression.DebugInfo(doc, 3, 1, 3, 100);

    var write = Expression.Call(infoWriteLine, localXYZ);

    // Line 4: return; 
    var debugInfo3 = Expression.DebugInfo(doc, 4, 1, 4, 100);

    var block = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[] { localXYZ }, new Expression[] { debugInfo1, assign, debugInfo2, write, debugInfo3 });
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<string[]>>(block, Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[])));

    // bake it 
    lambda.CompileToMethod(methodbuilder, generator);
    Type helloWorldType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    // This now calls the newly generated method. We can step into this and debug our emitted code!! 
    var dm = (Action<string[]>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string[]>), helloWorldType.GetMethod("MyMethod"));
    dm(new string[] { null }); // <-- step into this call 
}
```

Save this somewhere as Source.txt

```
1|  // Test
2|  xyz = "hello"; 
3|  Write(xyz); 
4|  return;
```

then put a breakpoint on the `dm(new string[] { null })`, and press F11 when on the bp. It will ask you for the `Source.txt`. Note that if you don't select it, you'll have to delete the `.suo` file to get the window a second time.

Note the use of the `DebuggableAttribute`. It seems it's the trick to mark the dynamic assembly as debuggable.

Comment: Still, when I want to make step debugging, VS asks me for the source file. Is the step debugging possible in this case?

Comment: Actually, if I remove SymbolDocument and DebugInfo from your code completely, it will still show the stack trace.

Comment: @XyiTebe But it won't show "MyDebug.txt" and "row 6". Those methods are used to put annotations in the Expression. I don't think you can "debug" Expression trees with Visual Studio

Comment: With Reflection.Emit, creating .il file and step debugging code with the created file was successful; with expression trees not yet. For reference: Hazzard & Bock "Metaprogramming in .Net", pp. 160 and 184 resp.

Comment: @XyiTebe How did you create the `il` file? Manually or how?

Comment: @XyiTebe Added something to the response.

Comment: To compile .il from Reflection.Emit see: http://www.manning.com/hazzard/ , in the source code for this book, Chapter 5, ReflectionEmitWithDebuggingMethodGenerator.cs and related files. There you can also find sample Chapter 6 - about Expressions. My question relates to pp.185-186

Comment: @XyiTebe The author "cheats" and doesn't tell you that there is no auto Expression generator and that you have to do everything by hand :-) You'll need to create an expression visitor to add the `Expression.DebugInfo` plus something to generate the `.exp` file. Quite complex (probably 1 week work to do it correctly). There is a forum about the book http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=732&start=0, you could ask the author there.

Comment: Seems that will be the answer - and a fun task to do on the free time. Thank you!